# Copy a AWS ECR image from one repository to another in the same account and region by lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I want to know if I can copy a ECR image tag from one repository to another repository in the same account and region by lambda function?

I have two repositories, they are in the same account and region.

1. dev-repo: this is for development stage. (Many images for internal test and develop.)
2. release-repo: this is for release stage. (Only keep stable image for customer use.)

Can I specify a stable image tag copy from dev-repo to release-repo by lambda function?
Because I want to make this action to a WebAPI, so I hope I can do this in lambda function, but not command line PULL/TAG/PUSH command.

I try to using putImage() API from AWS.ECR in lambda function, but I get the error:

This is my lambda function code:

```
    const ecr = new AWS.ECR({
        apiVersion: '2015-09-21',
        region: 'ap-northeast-1'
    });
    var params3 = {
     imageIds: [
        {
       imageTag: "latest"
      }
     ], 
     repositoryName: "dev-repo"
    };
    await ecr.batchGetImage(params3, function(err, data) {
        console.log(`[log] batchGetImage ----`);
        console.log(data.images[0].imageId);
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else {
          console.log(data);           // successful response
          _imageManifest = data.images[0].imageManifest;
          _imageDigest = data.images[0].imageId.imageDigest;
          _imageTag = data.images[0].imageId.imageTag;
          _imageManifestMediaType = data.images[0].imageManifestMediaType;
          _registryId = data.images[0].registryId;
      }
    }).promise();
    
    
    var params4 = {
      imageManifest: _imageManifest, /* required */
      repositoryName: 'release-repo', /* required */
      imageDigest: _imageDigest,
      imageManifestMediaType: _imageManifestMediaType,
      imageTag: _imageTag,
      registryId: _registryId
    };
    await ecr.putImage(params4, function(err, data) {
        console.log(`[log] putImage ----`);
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    }).promise();
```

But I get the below error:

```
{
  "errorType": "LayersNotFoundException",
  "errorMessage": "Layers with digests '[sha256:bf06eb87a616c35c96a20d27e321d128c8ffa3d3043be450e4cde55c40ae1234,sha256:b06e123492282da4881988d86ce029772688c184c8e3d4be8ca57324c132d914,sha256:484973927ef74670143940e917c8e337f3d80c792d7db606c02dc567b5a44a31,sha256:1fe172e4850f03bb45d41a20174112bc119fbfec42a650edbbd8491aee32e3c3,sha256:b42fa4ca85ad1bd3e1e9701a25947c802adfd6fd644fea6071d96996d008d25c,sha256:4ec24e6222d2a099523078066656652cc74b1e7ee6f24b316737e7c7efbab19b,sha256:2d76dbc42f5589cdb12df012aa20b07876ff1ced8426c28f2e2b86eda3f91234]' required for pushing image into repository with name 'release-repo' in the registry with id 'xxxxxxx' do not exist",
  "trace": [
    "LayersNotFoundException: Layers with digests '[sha256:bf06eb87a616c35c96a20d27e321d128c8ffa3d3043be450e4cde55c40ae1234,sha256:b06e123492282da4881988d86ce029772688c184c8e3d4be8ca57324c132d914,sha256:484973927ef74670143940e917c8e337f3d80c792d7db606c02dc567b5a44a31,sha256:1fe172e4850f03bb45d41a20174112bc119fbfec42a650edbbd8491aee32e3c3,sha256:b42fa4ca85ad1bd3e1e9701a25947c802adfd6fd644fea6071d96996d008d25c,sha256:4ec24e6222d2a099523078066656652cc74b1e7ee6f24b316737e7c7efbab19b,sha256:2d76dbc42f5589cdb12df012aa20b07876ff1ced8426c28f2e2b86eda3f91234]' required for pushing image into repository with name 'release-repo' in the registry with id 'xxxxxxx' do not exist",
    "    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)",
    "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
    "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
    "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)",
    "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)",
    "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
  ]
}
```

Can someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this would work since Lambda has a read-only filesystem. Maybe I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem possible for it to actually pull an image from ECR and store it in the Lambda environment temporarily. I think an AWS CodeBuild task would work much better than a Lambda function for this.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for your comment, CodeBuild is a new idea for me, I will try to survey this service now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Mark B's suggetion, I already try to use CodeBuild Service to copy our docker image from dev-repo to release-repo, and it's seems what we want!
In CodeBuild service, we can create a build project within a buildspec.yml to do the docker pull/ tag/ push actions.

buildspec.yml like below:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
       - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
       - aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Docker Pull and Tag...
      - docker pull ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME_FROM}${IMAGE_TAG_FROM}
      - docker tag ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME_FROM}${IMAGE_TAG_FROM} ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME_TO}${IMAGE_TAG_TO}
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME_TO}${IMAGE_TAG_TO}
```

In Lambda fuctions, we can trigger this CodeBuild project, with environement variable in codebuild.startBuild() api.